# Unique records query

Tags: unique

The following query is showing same user for multiple times, how to make it unique?

```
$query = 'SELECT   a.connection_id, a.connect_from, a.connect_to,
                   b.userid, b.thumb, c.name, d.user_id, d.field_id,
                   d.value as bday, e.creator, e.id as videoprofile,
                   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),d.value)), "%Y")+0 AS age
          FROM     `#__community_connection` AS a 
                   LEFT JOIN `#__community_users` AS b
                       ON a.connect_to = b.userid
                   LEFT JOIN `#__users` AS c ON a.connect_to = c.id
                   LEFT JOIN `#__community_fields_values` AS d
                       ON a.connect_to = d.user_id
                   LEFT JOIN `#__community_videos` AS e ON a.connect_to = e.creator
          WHERE    a.connect_from = "' . $uid .'" AND d.field_id = "3"
          ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH( bday ) ASC';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT` after your `SELECT` to return only unique rows. So change the first line of your code to the following:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT  a.connection_id, a.connect_from, a.connect_to, ...
[The rest of your query follows here.]
```

Comment: @Johan, +1 on your comment for moral support. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but I assume you want a unique identifacation method for your users?

Well in PHP you can hash their ip address and use that as their id, however it contains numbers and letters, so that'll make it unique i suppose :)

Here's how it'll look

```
.md5($data['post_ip']);
```

it'll appear different to everyone, for example, mine appears as the following
e36e263f082188a317f89e0dfef766ed

hopefully this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: -1, OP want to eliminate the duplicate rows he's getting in his query right now, adding a `distinct` will do that. An autoincrementing id will do fine for uniqueness, no MD5 magic required IMHO. Also note that the question was tagged `query` not `php` :-).